# Pinescript How can I replace source (close) from other symbol close in whole code to check if it meets the conditions?

Tags: arrays, loops, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

So I created TradingView indicator which contains some of free indicators. It has a lot of conditions to plot the signal BUY, something about ten (160 lines). And - I want to get for example "close" from BINANCE:ETHUSDT, then replace it with all "close" from my code and check if it meet the condition BUY. I spent a lot of hours analyzing other indicators with no results. I found out that I have to use array to replace and for loop. In the end - I want to get multiple alerts if one of symbols draw BUY signal. Any ideas how I could easily do it? Thanks :) [For example: ]

```
myClose1 = request.security("BTCUSDT", "5", close)
myClose2 = request.security("ETHUSDT", "5", close)
myClose3 = request.security("SOLUSDT", "5", close)

BUY = close > ta.vwma(close, 30)
alert(BUY)
(and other 159 lines with complicated code :P )

AND NOW ------->>>>> how to replace myClose 1,2,3 with close and check BUY condition for those 3 sources (with complicated code)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `close` on its own is not enough. You need to get all other information your conditions use.

However, you can just pass your buy condition to the `security()` and use the return value. So, instead of passing all those variables, just pass `BUY`.

```
BUY = close > ta.vwma(close, 30)
BUY_BTC = request.security("BTCUSDT", "5", BUY)
```

This will work for simple conditions. If the indicators you use are more complicated, you might need to request extra data and calculate the conditions yourself.

Comment: Acutally, it really worked! Thank you so much :) I spent something about 10h on this problem. I'm really grateful. Have a good day :)